# Is there any way to use PFUser instead of PFInstallation for data needed to target push notifications?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

All of my user's data that is needed to target and fire push notifications are in the `PFUser` object. I have just recently registered `PFInstallation` objects for each user with a property pointing to the `PFUser`.

I read through the [Parse.com docs push notification guide](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#push-notifications) that

> the Installation object is where you store all the data needed to
>   target push notifications.

Just wondering, is there any way to use the `PFUser` on the `installation` object to target push notifications? If not, what would be the best way to switch over all the data from the `PFUser` object over to the `PFInstallation` object?

Comment: You can only use PFInstallation and you may need to run cloud code on Parse to migrate necessary data to PFInstallation.

Comment: Are you looking to send push notifications to certain users?  If so this should help: https://parse.com/questions/sending-push-notifications-to-a-specific-user